# Powershell Send Key Excel

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, sendkeys

I would like to write a script in Powershell which does the following:

1. Opens Excel Workbook.
2. Click two times enter on the 2 appearing DialogBoxes.
3. Runs a macro, saves workbook and quits.

I have a problem with the 2nd step.  In my script enter is sent to Powershell window and I see two lines added to the code.

Could anyone help me? Here is my code:

```
$p1 = "C:\"
$eo = new-object -comobject excel.application; 
$eoc = dir $p1 -Include *.xlsm -Recurse              
Foreach ($f1 in $eoc)
{
   $wb = $eo.workbooks.open($f1.fullname)
   while (!$eo.Ready){sleep 0.1}
   $eo.Application.SendKeys('~')
   while (!$eo.Ready){sleep 0.1}
   $eo.Application.SendKeys('~');
   $eo.Run("macro_name"); 
   $eo.Application.CalculateFull; 
   while (!$eo.Ready){sleep 0.1};
   $wb.save(); $wb.close()
}
$eo.quit()
```

Comment: Sendkeys() usually fails due to focus or timing. Google for _AppActivate Method_.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this.

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;

$wshell.AppActivate('window name of your excel file') | Out-Null
```

This will focus your excel workbook and execute your send key commands.